# How to make a display:block <a> tag automatic resize to the text size?

Tags: html, css

If I specify a `<a>` tag to `display:block`, it will take a whole line's room. Is there anyway that I can make the space just fit to the text, not by specifying a fixed with (because the text can be very short or very long).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `display: block;` for `a` tag, which will take `100%` horizontal space by default, you can either use `float` or you can make it `display: inline-block;` which will keep the element as a `block` level element but `inline` as well.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9LCdw/)

Comment: It seems `inline-block` is a perfect solution? Any bad for using it every time?

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo Well, depends on your requirement, using `float`, you have to look out for clearing them, else your layouts will be messed up, when it comes to `inline-block`, you will get a white space for which you need to write all the `a` tag in your source without any indentation, also you might need `vertical-align: middle;` as well

Comment: Oh, I just figure out that if I use `inline-block`, the links won't automatic fits a new line. My expectation is to let each a tag fills a new line, but the box layout model only fits the content (text or image)'s size.

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo wrap the `a` tag text using a `span` tag, keep `a` tag as `display: block;` and use `border` on the `span` tag

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo Glad you liked :)

Answer (score 0):

```
a {    
    display: inline-block;
  }
```